# Passing json object using AJAX error in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

I have created an HTML file that will try to pass a json value to my asp page but I get an error on my asp. My HTML works ok and passing values {'a':'a','b':'b'}, but the asp page were not able to use the value.

1. Here is my HTML code and showing the JSON value {'a':'a','b':'b'}:

   ```
     <html>
     <head>
     <title></title>

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 

       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#btnAdd').click(function() { 


           var json_obj = "{'" + $('#t1').val() + "' : '" + $('#p1').val() + "','" + $('#t2').val() + "' : '" + $('#p2').val() + "'}"; 


           $.ajax({ 
               type: 'POST', 
               url: 'http://localhost/Base_Data/InsertItem.aspx', 
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
               data: json_obj, 
               dataType: 'json', 
               success: function(msg) { 
                   alert('Success!'); 
               }, 
               error: function(msg) { 
                   alert('Error!'); 
               } 
           }); 
       }); 
     }); 
     </script> 
     </head>
     <body>

   <div> 
   Type: 1: <input type="text" id="t1" /> 
   Property 1: <input type="text" id="p1" /> 

   Type 2: <input type="text" id="t2" /> 
   Property 2: <input type="text" id="p2" /> 
   <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add object!" /> 

   </div> 

   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Here is my ASP page code behind:

   ```
   public class Test
   {
   public Test(string json)
   {

       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);

       var first = int.Parse(result["t1"]);
       var second = int.Parse(result["t2"]); 
    }

     public string first { get; set; }
     public string second { get; set; }
    }
   ```

Any replies will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*but the asp page were not able to use the value*" - can you explain *why*?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using 't1' and 't2' as keys. The keys in your example are determined by user input in the field. your key $('#t1').val() will return what ever is in t1 field. If you want to use t1 and t2 as keys make json like {t1:value,t2:value}. Also like mentioned in one of the answers avoid manhandling JSON. Use something like, x={key1:value1,key2:value2}, a lot of times you dont even need to serialize it. If you must use JSON.stringiy(x).

Answer (score 0):

When passing data to the `$.ajax` method, the `data` parameter is generally a javascript object with key/value pairs and those key/value pairs are put into a query string as in `foo=bar&person=ted`.  Putting a JSON string in there and then trying to parse that JSON in your server is the hard way to send a couple values to your server and it's a lot more work to parse it on the server too.

Using the built in data capabilities of the `$.ajax` method will put the data into query string format and your server can automatically parse that out too - all without writing any new code on client or server.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> data
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string,
>   if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.
>   See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object
>   must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes
>   multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional
>   setting (described below).

Comment: No it's not, the `data` can be a string, if it is passed as a JS object it's converted to a query string.

Comment: @James - Does the OP's code expect the code to be passed to the server as an JSON string embedded into a query string?  Why do it that way?

Comment: No I think the OP expects the data to be passed to the server as a JSON string.

Comment: @James - why go to all that bother for four data values?  If the OP uses the `$.ajax` data object, then they get everything for free on client and server rather than having to construct and deconstruct JSON.

Comment: Hi guys im new to here, i just try  it from my readings about html passing json value to asp. i might go with isert sql in my asp page after this was solve. so how my variable should look like? and how to construct my code in asp to accept the value from my html?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I agree the OP probably should be using a JS object rather than constructing JSON themselves, or at least using a proper JSON parser. However, your answer seems to suggest that sending the data as a string is wrong - which it isn't. Also, the OP hasn't actually said what the problem was they state "*My HTML works ok and passing values*" - my guess is it's a problem parsing the JSON at the server rather than an issue sending it.

Comment: Hi James, my only problem now is that my asp wont accept the value from my html.. i will try to put the values in my "insert into my database" statement lately if I get the values right.. thanks...

Comment: @James - I modified the wording in my answer a little while ago.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Sorry I never noticed your edit, hadn't refreshed the page. However, there is probably still an argument for passing JSON if the data is large & complex. "*my asp won't accept the value from my html*" - what error are you getting? I would hazard a guess at your JSON being invalid.

Comment: Hi, var first = int.Parse(result["t1"]);
    var second = int.Parse(result["t2"]); display error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'. I will assume if i get the value of variables first and second from my HTML, i will display it via Response.write so i could test if im passing it right then I will make my insert into mydatabase the values i get..

Comment: You don't want to be calling `DeserializeObject` you want to deserialize your json into a `dynamic` object so you can access the fields via key - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid generating pure JSON manually as it can always lead to problems, try using something like [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which will make your data construction easier as you can use proper JS objects e.g.

```
var jsonObj = { t1: $('#t1').val(), p1: $('#p1').val(), t2: $('#t2').val(), p2: $('#p2').val() };

$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'http://localhost/Base_Data/InsertItem.aspx',  
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',  
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),  
    dataType: 'json',  
    success: function(msg) {  
        alert('Success!');  
    },  
    error: function(msg) {  
        alert('Error!');  
    }  
});
```

Then on the server side deserialize your json into a `dynamic` object and get the data back out:

```
public Test(string json)  
{  
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
    var result = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);  

    var first = int.Parse(result["t1"]);  
    var second = int.Parse(result["t2"]);   
}
```

**Update**

Based on your comment you won't be able to use a `dynamic` object, you should be able to deserialize your JSON into a `Dictionary` e.g.

```
var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: Hi James i have an error on APS. on <dynamic>.. it says "The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found".

Comment: @JR_13 what version of Visual Studio are you using? Think you need a minimum of 2010 to use `dynamic` type.

Comment: ,, im using VS 2008, is there any other way, the way vs2008 can handle it? thanks!